# Get cucumber datatable in hooks file using Ruby/Watir

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, integration, watir

First time here so I'll try to be most readable possible. I have a test in a feature file which uses a datatable for sorting some data as seen below:

[Current cucumber test example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBUBp.png)

Currently I am using `scenario.test_steps.map(&:name)` to get all the steps (this is necessary because of an integration to an application lifecycle software manager) in an array and this is what I get:

[Cucumber steps got in the hooks file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Wyd.png)

My question is: is it possible to get the datatable information in the **Before do |scenario|** hook over the hooks file?

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps!

Answer (score 1):

When iterating through `scenario.test_steps`, each test step has an associated `Cucumber::Core::Ast::Step`. This contains the step specific information such as the step name, data table, etc. The associated `Ast::Step` will be the last element of the test step's `source`:

```
test_step.source
#=> [
#=>   #<Cucumber::Core::Ast::Feature "Feature: Something" (features/something.feature:1)>,
#=>   #<Cucumber::Core::Ast::Scenario "Scenario: Only a test" (features/something.feature:3)>, 
#=>   #<Cucumber::Core::Ast::Step "Given : the fields" (features/something.feature:4)>
#=> ]
```

To access the `Ast::Step` multi-line argument, check the `multiline_arg`. If a data table has been specified, an `Ast::DataTable` will be returned. Otherwise, an `Ast::EmptyMultilineArgument` will be returned. You can check if the returned value is a data table by calling `data_table?`.

As an example, the below would iterate through each test step and output the data table if defined:

```
Before do |scenario|    
  scenario.test_steps.each do |test_step|
    multiline_arg = test_step.source.last.multiline_arg
    puts multiline_arg.raw if multiline_arg.data_table?
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Justin Ko. I copy and paste exactly as you put it but didn't work so I did some changes using a `begin rescue` block and _voilá_ it worked!